# EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash when start running app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, exc-bad-access, linphone

i use linphone SDK in my application. When i start to run app crash happening immediately.
After app start it's call `[Fastaddreesbook init]` which called `[FastAddreesBook reload]` which called `[FastAddreesBook loadData]` which called `[FastAddreesBook normalizeSipURI]` and **exc_bad_access** Crash happen in this method:

```
LinphoneAddress* linphoneAddress = linphone_core_interpret_url([LinphoneManager getLc], [address UTF8String]);
```

**Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)**

```
  /* FastAddressBook.h
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2011  Belledonne Comunications, Grenoble, France
 *
 *  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
 *  (at your option) any later version.
 *
 *  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 *  GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 *  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 *  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
 *  Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307, USA.
 */
#ifdef __IPHONE_9_0
#import <Contacts/Contacts.h>
#endif
#import "FastAddressBook.h"
#import "LinphoneManager.h"
#import "BundleLocalData.h"
#import "AppUtil.h"
#import "WebserviceUtil.h"
#import "ContactEntry.h"
#import "ContactsViewController.h"

@implementation FastAddressBook

static void sync_address_book (ABAddressBookRef addressBook, CFDictionaryRef info, void *context);

+ (NSString*)getContactDisplayName:(ABRecordRef)contact {
    NSString *retString = nil;
    if (contact) {
        CFStringRef lDisplayName = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(contact);
        if(lDisplayName != NULL) {
            retString = [NSString stringWithString:(NSString*)lDisplayName];
            CFRelease(lDisplayName);
        }
    }
    return retString;
}

+ (UIImage*)squareImageCrop:(UIImage*)image
{
    UIImage *ret = nil;

    // This calculates the crop area.

    float originalWidth  = image.size.width;
    float originalHeight = image.size.height;

    float edge = fminf(originalWidth, originalHeight);

    float posX = (originalWidth - edge) / 2.0f;
    float posY = (originalHeight - edge) / 2.0f;


    CGRect cropSquare = CGRectMake(posX, posY,
                                   edge, edge);


    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, cropSquare);
    ret = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef
                              scale:image.scale
                        orientation:image.imageOrientation];

    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return ret;
}

+ (UIImage*)getContactImage:(ABRecordRef)contact thumbnail:(BOOL)thumbnail {
    UIImage* retImage = nil;
    if (contact && ABPersonHasImageData(contact)) {
        CFDataRef imgData = ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(contact, thumbnail?
                                                            kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail: kABPersonImageFormatOriginalSize);

        retImage = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)imgData];
        if(imgData != NULL) {
            CFRelease(imgData);
        }

        if (retImage != nil && retImage.size.width != retImage.size.height) {
            [LinphoneLogger log:LinphoneLoggerLog format:@"Image is not square : cropping it."];
            return [self squareImageCrop:retImage];
        }
    }

    return retImage;
}

- (ABRecordRef)getContact:(NSString*)address {
    @synchronized (addressBookMap){
        return (ABRecordRef)addressBookMap[address];
    }
}

+ (BOOL)isSipURI:(NSString*)address {
    return [address hasPrefix:@"sip:"] || [address hasPrefix:@"sips:"];
}

+ (NSString*)appendCountryCodeIfPossible:(NSString*)number {
    if (![number hasPrefix:@"+"] && ![number hasPrefix:@"00"]) {
        NSString* lCountryCode = [[LinphoneManager instance] lpConfigStringForKey:@"countrycode_preference"];
        if (lCountryCode && lCountryCode.length>0) {
            //append country code
            return [lCountryCode stringByAppendingString:number];
        }
    }
    return number;
}

+ (NSString*)normalizeSipURI:(NSString*)address {
    NSString *normalizedSipAddress = nil;
    LinphoneAddress* linphoneAddress = linphone_core_interpret_url([LinphoneManager getLc], [address UTF8String]);
    if(linphoneAddress != NULL) {
        char *tmp = linphone_address_as_string_uri_only(linphoneAddress);
        if(tmp != NULL) {
            normalizedSipAddress = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:tmp];
            ms_free(tmp);
        }
        linphone_address_destroy(linphoneAddress);
    }
    return normalizedSipAddress;
}

+ (NSString*)normalizePhoneNumber:(NSString*)address {
    NSMutableString* lNormalizedAddress = [NSMutableString stringWithString:address];
    [lNormalizedAddress replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                                        withString:@""
                                           options:0
                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, lNormalizedAddress.length)];
    [lNormalizedAddress replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"("
                                        withString:@""
                                           options:0
                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, lNormalizedAddress.length)];
    [lNormalizedAddress replaceOccurrencesOfString:@")"
                                        withString:@""
                                           options:0
                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, lNormalizedAddress.length)];
    [lNormalizedAddress replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"-"
                                        withString:@""
                                           options:0
                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, lNormalizedAddress.length)];
    return [FastAddressBook appendCountryCodeIfPossible:lNormalizedAddress];
}

+ (BOOL)isAuthorized {
    //addme  //  return !ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus || ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() ==  kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized;
    return ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized;
}


- (FastAddressBook*)init {
    if ((self = [super init]) != nil) {
        addressBookMap  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        addressBook = nil;
        [self reload];
    }


    self.needToUpdate = FALSE;
    if ([CNContactStore class]) {
        //ios9 or later
        CNEntityType entityType = CNEntityTypeContacts;
        if([CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:entityType] == CNAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
            CNContactStore * contactStore = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
            //   nslo(@"CNContactStore requesting authorization");
            [contactStore requestAccessForEntityType:entityType completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                //        LOGD(@"CNContactStore authorization granted");
            }];
        } else if([CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:entityType]== CNAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
            //   LOGD(@"CNContactStore authorization granted");
        }
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateAddressBook:) name:CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    }


    return self;
}




-(void) updateAddressBook:(NSNotification*) notif {
    // LOGD(@"address book has changed");
    self.needToUpdate = TRUE;
}




- (void) checkContactListForJogvoiceList {
    //    if (![BundleLocalData isLoadingJogvoiceContactList]) {
    //        [BundleLocalData setLoadingJogvoiceContactList:true];

    int maxPhoneNumberSubmit = 200;
    NSArray *lContacts = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    NSMutableDictionary *phoneNumberContactsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *allPhoneNumberList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (id lPerson in lContacts) {
        ABRecordRef person = (ABRecordRef)lPerson;
        NSArray *phoneList = [AppUtil getContactPhoneList:person];
        for (NSString* phoneNumber in phoneList) {
            NSMutableArray* contactList = phoneNumberContactsDictionary[phoneNumber];
            if (!contactList) {
                contactList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            }
            [contactList addObject:(__bridge ABRecordRef)person];
            phoneNumberContactsDictionary[phoneNumber] = contactList;
        }
        [allPhoneNumberList addObjectsFromArray:phoneList];

        if (allPhoneNumberList.count >= maxPhoneNumberSubmit) {
            [self checkContactList:allPhoneNumberList phoneNumberContactsDictionary:phoneNumberContactsDictionary];
        }
    }

    if (allPhoneNumberList.count > 0) {
        [self checkContactList:allPhoneNumberList phoneNumberContactsDictionary:phoneNumberContactsDictionary];
    }


    //        ABAddressBookUnregisterExternalChangeCallback(addressBook, sync_address_book, self);

    //        [BundleLocalData setLoadingJogvoiceContactList:false];
    //    }
}

-(void) checkContactList:(NSMutableArray*)allPhoneNumberList phoneNumberContactsDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary*)phoneNumberContactsDictionary {

    [WebserviceUtil apiGetUsersRegistered:[NSArray arrayWithArray:allPhoneNumberList]
                                  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){

                                      NSDictionary* response = responseObject;
                                      for (id phoneNumber in allPhoneNumberList) {
                                          NSNumber *status = response[phoneNumber];
                                          if (status.intValue == 1) { // registered
                                              NSArray* contactList = phoneNumberContactsDictionary[phoneNumber];
                                              for (int index = 0; index < contactList.count; index++) {
                                                  ABRecordRef contact = (__bridge ABRecordRef) contactList[index];
                                                  [self saveContact:phoneNumber contact:contact];
                                              }
                                          }
                                      }
                                      [self saveAddressBook];
                                      [allPhoneNumberList removeAllObjects];

                                  } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                      // nothing
                                  }];

}

-(void) saveContact:(NSString*)phoneNumber contact:(ABRecordRef)contact {

    if(contact == NULL || phoneNumber == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    ABMultiValueRef lMap = ABRecordCopyValue(contact, kABPersonInstantMessageProperty);
    if (!lMap) {
        return;
    }
    BOOL avafoneAlready = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(lMap); ++i) {
        ABMultiValueIdentifier identifier = ABMultiValueGetIdentifierAtIndex(lMap, i);
        CFDictionaryRef lDict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(lMap, i);
        if(CFDictionaryContainsKey(lDict, kABPersonInstantMessageServiceKey)) {
            if(CFStringCompare((CFStringRef)[LinphoneManager instance].contactSipField, CFDictionaryGetValue(lDict, kABPersonInstantMessageServiceKey), kCFCompareCaseInsensitive) == 0) {
                avafoneAlready = true;
            }
        } else {
            //check domain
            LinphoneAddress* address = linphone_address_new(((NSString*)CFDictionaryGetValue(lDict,kABPersonInstantMessageUsernameKey)).UTF8String);
            if (address) {
                if ([[ContactSelection getSipFilter] compare:@"*" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) {
                    avafoneAlready = true;
                } else {
                    NSString* domain = [NSString stringWithCString:linphone_address_get_domain(address)
                                                          encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
                    if ([domain compare:[ContactSelection getSipFilter] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) {
                        avafoneAlready = true;
                    }
                }
                linphone_address_destroy(address);
            }
        }
        CFRelease(lDict);
        if(avafoneAlready) {
            avafoneAlready = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    CFRelease(lMap);

    if (avafoneAlready) {
        return;
    }
    NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"900%@", phoneNumber];
    ContactEntry *entry = nil;

    ABMultiValueRef lcMap = ABRecordCopyValue(contact, kABPersonInstantMessageProperty);
    if(lcMap != NULL) {
        lMap = ABMultiValueCreateMutableCopy(lcMap);
        CFRelease(lcMap);
    } else {
        lMap = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABStringPropertyType);
    }
    ABMultiValueIdentifier index;
    NSError* error = NULL;

    CFStringRef keys[] = { kABPersonInstantMessageUsernameKey,  kABPersonInstantMessageServiceKey};
    CFTypeRef values[] = { [value copy], [LinphoneManager instance].contactSipField };
    CFDictionaryRef lDict = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, (const void **)&keys, (const void **)&values, 2, NULL, NULL);
    if (entry) {
        index = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(lMap, entry.identifier);
        ABMultiValueReplaceValueAtIndex(lMap, lDict, index);
    } else {
        CFStringRef label = (CFStringRef)[NSString stringWithString:(NSString*)kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel];
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(lMap, lDict, label, &index);
    }

    if (!ABRecordSetValue(contact, kABPersonInstantMessageProperty, lMap, (CFErrorRef*)&error)) {
        [LinphoneLogger log:LinphoneLoggerLog format:@"Can't set contact with value [%@] cause [%@]", value,error.localizedDescription];
        CFRelease(lMap);
    } else {
        if (entry == nil) {
            entry = [[[ContactEntry alloc] initWithData:index] autorelease];
        }
        CFRelease(lDict);
        CFRelease(lMap);

        /*check if message type is kept or not*/
        lcMap = ABRecordCopyValue(contact, kABPersonInstantMessageProperty);
        lMap = ABMultiValueCreateMutableCopy(lcMap);
        CFRelease(lcMap);
        index = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(lMap, entry.identifier);
        lDict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(lMap,index);
        //        if(!CFDictionaryContainsKey(lDict, kABPersonInstantMessageServiceKey)) {
        /*too bad probably a gtalk number, storing uri*/
        NSString* username = CFDictionaryGetValue(lDict, kABPersonInstantMessageUsernameKey);
        LinphoneAddress* address = linphone_core_interpret_url([LinphoneManager getLc]
                                                               ,username.UTF8String);
        if(address){
            char* uri = linphone_address_as_string_uri_only(address);
            CFStringRef keys[] = { kABPersonInstantMessageUsernameKey,  kABPersonInstantMessageServiceKey};
            CFTypeRef values[] = { [NSString stringWithCString:uri encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]], [LinphoneManager instance].contactSipField };
            CFDictionaryRef lDict2 = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, (const void **)&keys, (const void **)&values, 2, NULL, NULL);
            ABMultiValueReplaceValueAtIndex(lMap, lDict2, index);
            if (!ABRecordSetValue(contact, kABPersonInstantMessageProperty, lMap, (CFErrorRef*)&error)) {
                [LinphoneLogger log:LinphoneLoggerLog format:@"Can't set contact with value [%@] cause [%@]", value,error.localizedDescription];
            }
            CFRelease(lDict2);
            linphone_address_destroy(address);
            ms_free(uri);
        }
        //        }
        CFDictionaryRef lDict = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, (const void **)&keys, (const void **)&values, 2, NULL, NULL);
        ABMultiValueReplaceValueAtIndex(lMap, lDict, index);
        CFRelease(lMap);
    }
    CFRelease(lDict);



}

- (void)saveAddressBook {
    if( addressBook != nil ){
        NSError* err = nil;
        if( !ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, (CFErrorRef*)err) ){
            Linphone_warn(@"Couldn't save Address Book");
        }
    }
}

- (void)reload {
     NSLog(@"Fastadd reload first is loaded");


     CFErrorRef error;

     // create if it doesn't exist
     if (addressBook == nil) {
     addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);
     }

     if (addressBook != nil) {
     __weak FastAddressBook *weakSelf = self;
     ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
     if (!granted) {
     Linphone_warn(@"Permission for address book acces was denied: %@", [(__bridge NSError *)error description]);
     return;
     }

     ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(addressBook, sync_address_book, (__bridge void *)(weakSelf));
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
     [weakSelf loadData];
     });

     });
     } else {
     Linphone_warn(@"Create AddressBook failed, reason: %@", [(__bridge NSError *)error localizedDescription]);
     }




    /*
    //method1

     if(addressBook != nil) {
     ABAddressBookUnregisterExternalChangeCallback(addressBook, sync_address_book, self);
     CFRelease(addressBook);
     addressBook = nil;
     }
     NSError *error = nil;

     addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
     if(addressBook != NULL) {
     ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
     ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback (addressBook, sync_address_book, self);
     [self loadData];
     });
     } else {
     [LinphoneLogger log:LinphoneLoggerError format:@"Create AddressBook: Fail(%@)", [error localizedDescription]];
     }

    */



     }






- (void)loadData {
    ABAddressBookRevert(addressBook);
    @synchronized (addressBookMap) {
        [addressBookMap removeAllObjects];
        //melog
        NSLog(@"Fastadd loaddata is loaded");
        NSArray *lContacts = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
        for (id lPerson in lContacts) {
            // Phone
            {
                ABMultiValueRef lMap = ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef)lPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
                if(lMap) {
                    for (int i=0; i<ABMultiValueGetCount(lMap); i++) {
                        CFStringRef lValue = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(lMap, i);
                        CFStringRef lLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(lMap, i);
                        CFStringRef lLocalizedLabel = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(lLabel);
                        NSString* lNormalizedKey = [FastAddressBook normalizePhoneNumber:(NSString*)lValue];
                        NSString* lNormalizedSipKey = [FastAddressBook normalizeSipURI:lNormalizedKey];
                        if (lNormalizedSipKey != NULL) lNormalizedKey = lNormalizedSipKey;
                        addressBookMap[lNormalizedKey] = lPerson;
                        CFRelease(lValue);
                        if (lLabel) CFRelease(lLabel);
                        if (lLocalizedLabel) CFRelease(lLocalizedLabel);
                    }
                    CFRelease(lMap);
                }
            }

            // SIP
            {
                ABMultiValueRef lMap = ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef)lPerson, kABPersonInstantMessageProperty);
                if(lMap) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(lMap); ++i) {
                        CFDictionaryRef lDict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(lMap, i);
                        BOOL add = false;
                        if(CFDictionaryContainsKey(lDict, kABPersonInstantMessageServiceKey)) {
                            CFStringRef contactSipField = (CFStringRef)[LinphoneManager instance].contactSipField;
                            if (!contactSipField) {
                                contactSipField = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, "SIP", kCFStringEncodingMacRoman);
                            }
                            if(CFStringCompare(contactSipField, CFDictionaryGetValue(lDict, kABPersonInstantMessageServiceKey), kCFCompareCaseInsensitive) == 0) {
                                add = true;
                            }
                        } else {
                            add = true;
                        }
                        if(add) {

                            CFStringRef lValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(lDict, kABPersonInstantMessageUsernameKey);
                            NSString* lNormalizedKey = [FastAddressBook normalizeSipURI:(NSString*)lValue];
                            if(lNormalizedKey != NULL) {
                                addressBookMap[lNormalizedKey] = lPerson;
                            } else {
                                addressBookMap[(NSString*)lValue] = lPerson;
                            }


                            /*
                            NSString *lValue =
                            (__bridge NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(lDict, kABPersonInstantMessageUsernameKey);
                            NSString *lNormalizedKey = [FastAddressBook normalizeSipURI:lValue];
                            if (lNormalizedKey != NULL) {
                                [addressBookMap setObject:(__bridge id)(lPerson)forKey:lNormalizedKey];
                            } else {
                                [addressBookMap setObject:(__bridge id)(lPerson)forKey:lValue];
                            }

                            */
                        }
                       CFRelease(lDict);
                    }
                   CFRelease(lMap);
                }
            }
        }
        CFRelease(lContacts);
    }
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kLinphoneAddressBookUpdate object:self];
}


void sync_address_book (ABAddressBookRef addressBook, CFDictionaryRef info, void *context) {
    FastAddressBook* fastAddressBook = (FastAddressBook*)context;
    [fastAddressBook loadData];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    ABAddressBookUnregisterExternalChangeCallback(addressBook, sync_address_book, self);
    CFRelease(addressBook);
    [addressBookMap release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

P.S.:

-i use non-arc project

-zombie enable too but nothing change.

-Ivalue is will and thats because crash happening.

Debug Console:
warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available.

[image][image]

Comment: This is basic debugging my friend. You're trying to access a 0 pointer. Step through the code and see why it's 0 and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
LinphoneAddress* linphoneAddress = linphone_core_interpret_url([LinphoneManager getLc], [address UTF8String]);
```

`address` is nil.  Figure out why that is and you've got your crash source.   It likely should be nil as it is probably an optional field in the original record.

That code is a bit of a mess, btw.   It isn't following the standard patterns (lots of method prefixed with `get`, for example).  It really should be modernized and have ARC enabled.

Comment: (IValue is nil but IDict has value.)                                                                     this line return nil but i don't know why?  CFStringRef lValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(lDict, kABPersonInstantMessageUsernameKey);

Comment: Because there is no value for that key.   The user doesn’t have an instant message username.

Comment: why code is ok in simulator but not work in real device.maybe it's have memory issue.

Comment: @MehdiNegahban The problem is straightforward;  a user doesn't have an instant message username.  Figure that out.  Everything else is a distraction.